# automatically use python-mode with psp files in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am using Emacs 24.3, and would like to have .psp (python server pages) files automatically be in python-mode when opened as opposed to the default Fundamental mode. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`auto-mode-alist`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoModeAlist). Something like this in your configuration should do the trick:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
             '("\\.psp\\'" . python-mode))
```